# How to add Image, from Path in RDLC Report

Tags: image, path, reporting, rdlc

Helllo, How to add image from Path In RDLC report?? Where in database only image name is saved.

And Reporting Code Like that

```
{
    EmployeeDataSetTableAdapters.tblAdditionalInfoTableAdapter adpPic = new    EmployeeDataSetTableAdapters.tblAdditionalInfoTableAdapter();
    EmployeeDataSet.tblAdditionalInfoDataTable tblPic = new EmployeeDataSet.tblAdditionalInfoDataTable();
    adpPic.Fill(tblPic);
    ReportDataSource mds2 = new ReportDataSource("Pics", (DataTable)tblPic);

    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("PrintID.rdlc");

    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(mds2);
    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below links. It will explain how images add in RDLC Report.
The video contain a demo of works

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxS323bLdFs

http://easyprogrammingtechniques.blogspot.in/2014/02/how-to-add-image-in-rdlc-report.html

Comment: You should post answer as explaining the content here and not the link, because if the link got deleted your answer is useless.